# How to fix connectex error when trying to access SQL Server instance on Cloud SQL using SSMS via Proxy

Tags: sql-server, google-cloud-platform, ssms, google-cloud-sdk, google-cloud-proxy

## What I'm trying to do

I am trying to manage my SQL Server instance on Cloud SQL (GCP) with SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS).

## What I've done

I followed the steps in the Google Cloud documentation ([here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/sqlserver/quickstart)).
I followed steps 1-5 (condensed version below):

1. Install Cloud SQL
2. Run `gcloud init`
3. Run `gcloud auth login` (P.S. I'm Owner on Project level)
4. Download and install Google Cloud SQL Proxy (as per the instructions [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/sqlserver/connect-external-app))

   1. Enable Cloud SQL Admin API
   2. Install the proxy client (Windows PC for me, x64 - renamed file to `cloud_sql_proxy.exe`)
   3. Determine proxy authentication method (as per documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/sqlserver/sql-proxy#authentication-options)). I chose Cloud SDK since I need to download it in step 1 anyway
   4. Skip (not using service account authentication)
   5. Determine proxy instance specification (as per documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/sqlserver/sql-proxy#instances-options)). Using *Instances specified on proxy invocation* method.

      - I only have private IP, so by default it will select the correct IP (as per documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/sqlserver/sql-proxy#private-ip))
   6. Same as step 5 (below)
      5 . Start the proxy. I ran (in cmd) `./cloud_sql_proxy -instances=<INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>=tcp:1433` (obviously replacing the `<INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>` portion with my instance name.

At this point, everything seems to be working:

```
Listening on 127.0.0.1:1433 for <INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>
Ready for new connections
New connection for <INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>
New connection for <INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>
```

Now following the instructions [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/sqlserver/quickstart#connect-using-object-explorer), I attempt to connect to the database instance using SSMS (`127.0.0.1`, *SQL Server Authentication*, `sqlserver`, *my super awesome password*), Connect.

## My issue

I now get the following error messages in the Cloud SDK window:

```
couldn't connect to <INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>: dial tcp <PRIVATE_IP>:<PORT>: connectex: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
Throttline refreshCfg(<INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>: it was only called XXXs ago
```

(and it repeats a few times)

In SSMS I get the following prompt:

[image: SSMS error message]

## My question

How do I fix this issue and properly connect to my database instance?

Comment: Wondering why this might be considered community-specific when other similar questions exist across the site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When setting the Connectivity settings for the SQL Server instance, I changed it to `Private IP` and unchecked the `Public IP` setting. **Re-enabling the `Public IP` setting allowed me to establish a connection**:

[image: Cloud SQL Connectivity settings]

> External applications can still connect to the instance through the Cloud SQL Proxy

This indirectly indicates to me that Cloud SQL Proxy needs the `Public IP` option to be enabled in order to establish a connection.